# Installing Python 2 and 3 separately

Tags: python, bash, python-2.7, python-3.x, osx-mavericks

Is there a way to install python 2 and python 3 on Mac OSX together and be able to switch back and forth? I use Python 2 and 3 for development and I used to be able to do this virtualenv thing where I do source deactivate the development environment. But I wasn't sure how I set that up and it started to get very confusing for the compiler because I apparently installed some modules in one place and it works on python 2 but not 3 (or vice versa) and things are just all over the place. So I am wiping out my whole laptop and this time I want to do this installation business right. Is there any way I can switch back and forth python 2 and 3 with the compiler detecting just one set of library?

Comment: I don't understand your problem, I've got 2.5, 2.6, 2.6, 3.2, 3.3, 3.4, pypy and pypy3 all happily coexisting on OSX. The only bits you should pay attention to is being explicit which interpreter you are using and possible confusion if you have Apple-built and python.org python with same version (executables in /usr/bin and /usr/local/bin respectively). Not sure what you mean by `compiler`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, install [homebrew](http://brew.sh/) - it's the fundamental tool for managing installation on your Mac.

Now, using homebrew, install separate versions of Python and and Python 3:

```
$ brew install python
...
$ brew install python3
```

This should automatically install the relevant versions of pip for each version of Python as well as virtualenv. So you can now create a virtual environment for a Python 2 project:

```
$ virtualenv --python=python2.7 my_project
```

and for a Python 3 one:

```
$ virtualenv --python=python3 my_py3_project
```

and activate/deactivate them as you need.

Comment: OP does *not* need homebrew. A .dmg from python.org should do just fine.

Comment: He may not need homebrew, but it'll make his life easier in the long run...and it's not exactly difficult to install.

Answer (score 5):

[Virtualenv](http://virtualenv.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) is the default answer to that and it's explained well throughout their pages and across the web. An alternative, which does not depend on the shell, is its "reincarnation" as a Python module, pew, the [Python Env Wrapper](https://github.com/berdario/invewrapper).

Both will allow you to have separate interpreters, even for entirely different version numbers.